# jQuery .stop() Callback issue

Tags: jquery, callback

I'm trying to trigger an animation as a callback to another animation.  The things is I only want the second animation to fire if the first completes, and from what I've read that is how the .stop() function is supposed to work.  In the code I've compiled however, the second animation fires even if the first does not complete.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var angle = 0;

    function arrowRotate() {
        angle +=180;
        $('#arrow img').stop().rotate({
            animateTo: angle,
        }, 100);
    };

    function ToggleOpen(heightValue) {
        $('#information').stop().animate({
            height : heightValue,
        }, 1500, 'easeOutExpo', function(){
            arrowRotate();
        })
    };

    $('#information_container').hover(function(){
        ToggleOpen(500);

    }, function(){
        ToggleOpen(0);
    });

    $('#arrow img').click(function(){
        ToggleOpen(0);
    });

});
```

I'm using this third-party plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Here's the live implementation: http://hopeandpurpose.org

So basically what I'm trying to accomplish is raising the height of a div on hover, and once that completes an image rotates.  The problem is that the image still rotates even if the height animation does not complete and the div animates back to 0.

As I'm looking at the code now it seems that my problem is probably that as it hovers off, it triggers the arrowRotate() function.  Would an if function wrapping the arrowRotate() function be my best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `stop(true)` to stop the animation, and also clear any queued animations waiting to run on the element.

Here's an example. If you mouse off before the height shrinks, you'll see that that animation is not run because it's cleared by `stop(true)` in the mouseleave handler.

```js
$("div").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true).animate({ width: 300 }, function() {
      $(this).animate({ height: 50 });
    });
  }, function() {
    $(this).stop(true).animate({ width: 50, height: 100 });
  }
);
```

```css
#test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">Test</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I get the same result with your code regardless if the true parameter is passed or not though.  I think my issue may be slightly more complex than your example in that I need to fire a callback in the mouseleave handler as well.  Essentially, the arrow should rotate down (180deg) once the div is fully raised and then rotate back to 360deg once the div is lowered.